# あのレストラン vs そのレストラン in this conversation

Tags: grammar, kosoado

> A: 昨日おいしいレストランへ行ったんだっけ。
> B: へえ。そのレストラン、なんの料理のお店？
> A: イタリア料理。映画館の隣にある。
> B: ああ、**XX** レストランなら、私も行ったことがある。

Should XX be あの, or その?

Answer (score 1):

Both あの and その work perfectly fine. そのレストラン simply refers to the restaurant A is talking about. あのレストラン sounds like B is imagining the restaurant and referring to it.

You can think あのレストラン sounds a little more vivid. In English, そのレストラン is simply "the restaurant" or "that restaurant", but when you say "(oh) *that* restaurant" with emphasized *that*, it's closer to あのレストラン.